# Angular HTTPClient POST body not sending

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, post, angular-httpclient

Currently I am trying to POST a name, email and message from an angular frontend to a php script running in the same nginx server which then runs phpmailer to send an email containing the name, email and message. Here is the code so far:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Email } from './email';
import {ContactService} from './contact.service';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  })
};

const email = new Email('', '', '');

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.css'],
  providers: [ContactService]
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  email = new Email('', '', '');

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  sendEmail(form: NgForm) {
    const value = form.value;
    const senderName = value.name;
    const senderEmail = value.email;
    const senderMessage = value.message;
    this.sendMail(senderName, senderEmail, senderMessage);
  }

  sendMail(senderName, senderEmail, senderMessage) {
    console.log(senderName + ' ' + senderEmail + ' ' + senderMessage);
    this.http.post('https://ruffstuffcostumes.tk/assets/scripts/email.php',
      {
        name: senderName,
        email: senderEmail,
        message: senderMessage,
      },
      httpOptions
      )
      .subscribe(
        (val) => {
          console.log('POST call successful value returned in body',
            val);
        },
        response => {
          console.log('POST call in error', response);
        },
        () => {
          console.log('The POST observable is now completed.');
        });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

When I ran the POST request through postman to check it, it ran perfectly well and sent out the email containing the required elements, however when I execute a query with this script, even though the `console.log(senderName + ' ' + senderEmail + ' ' + senderMessage)` does show the values, it doesn't seem to post them in the body at all, and all I get back is the fact that even though a mail was sent, it was sent without any of those values in the body of the email.

Could it be cross-origin problems (and if so what would be the best way to get around that?), or am I just doing some stupid mistake?

Comment: If you check in the browser develop tools (F12), and then the network tab, can you see what is being sent?

Comment: @user184994 Yes, It's sending: `https://url/assets/scripts/email.php?name=username&email=email@protonmail.com&message=hi,%20it%20works!!` So it does seem to be dispensing data, but weirdly the php script doesn't seem to want to pick it up

Comment: The headers it's also sending are: `POST /assets/scripts/email.php?name=username&email=email@protonmail.com&message=hi,%20it%20works!! HTTP/1.1
Host: url
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://url
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3477.0 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: https://url/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Cookie: __cfduid=d41abcfedcaa744a8de652dcbe37dab021530345277
`

Comment: Yep, any reason you're not using JSON?

Comment: @user184994 Mainly because I've no clue on how to do json POST body decoding in php. Also, hadn't really thought of it

Comment: From your headers: `Content-Length: 0` - You aren't posting any data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for completeness. I solved the problem by switching to sending JSON data and parsing it on the php side